How to fix missing column in Go code when using SQLite
i have a table in sqlite database:
sqlite>.schema mmdb_csv
CREATE TABLE mmdb_csv (
cidr TEXT,
asn TEXT
);

I have uploaded a csv file with the following structure to this table:
cidr, asn,autonomous_system_organization,isp,organization
sqlite>.mode csv
sqlite>.import /home/igor/go/src/universal_blocklist_service2/mmdb-csv.csv mmdb_csv  

Also i have this code in my progarmm:
str := fmt.Sprint("SELECT cidr FROM ", conf.SQLiteASN2CIDR, " WHERE asn=?;")
        w.FindCidrsStmt, err = w.DBase.Prepare(str)
        if err != nil {
            w.log.Fatal().Msgs(err, " from NewRepairStruct()")
        }

data, err := w.FindCidrsStmt.Query(asn)
    if err != nil { 
        w.log.Error().Msgs(err, " from getCIDRs() 1, asn=", asn)
        return nil
    }


conf.SQLiteASN2CIDR=mmdb_csv
And I get following log:
"SQL logic error: no such column: cidr (1) from getCIDRs() 1, asn=59711"

But when I make an SQL query from the terminal, everything works as it should:
sqlite> select cidr from mmdb_csv where asn=59711 limit 10;
5.149.248.0/23
5.149.254.0/23
77.83.196.0/23
77.83.198.0/24
79.141.164.0/23
79.141.172.0/24
79.141.174.0/23
88.218.206.0/24
91.193.18.0/24
91.250.244.0/24

Why do i get this log message?:
"SQL logic error: no such column: cidr (1) from getCIDRs() 1, asn=59711"

When i add quotes around cidr in statement preparation i get no error logs, but there are no rows in data:
str := fmt.Sprint("SELECT \"cidr\" FROM ", conf.SQLiteASN2CIDR, " WHERE \"asn\"=?;")
        w.FindCidrsStmt, err = w.DBase.Prepare(str)
        if err != nil {
            w.log.Fatal().Msgs(err, " from NewRepairStruct()")
        }

data, err := w.FindCidrsStmt.Query(asn)
    if err != nil { 
        w.log.Error().Msgs(err, " from getCIDRs() 1, asn=", asn)
        return nil
    }

data here has no rows, and
for data.Next() {

is not being executed

You're not using sprintf correctly. The first argument is treated as a format string and the rest is treated as parameters for filling in placeholders. Except there aren't any.

What you execute in your Go program does not match what you execute in SQLite console: in the latter you select … from mmdb_csv … (that is, a plain table), in the former you select from "something" which is the result of evaluating a Go expression conf.SQLiteASN2CIDR, which can be any string.

While not directly related, please pay close attention to what Botje wrote: you appear to cargo-cult fmt.*f functions to construct strings. These functions only come in handy when you need complex formatting, and in your case there's just plain string concatenation which is perfetctly handled by the + operator alone.

@kostix, I wrote in my question that conf.SQLiteASN2CIDR is equal to "mmdb_csv", so final query is equal to "select cidr from mmdb_csv where asn=?"

I think your function is cleared, so I suspect that you didn't input the database name when initialized the connection or maybe it's calling to another DB because the DB Name is inputted with another value.
